# httppost is returning null

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to insert data into mysql database through my android application. Httppost is not returning null every time. Whenever the app is executed httppost is containg null.
It goes to the exception invalid ip address. But the url is working fine when searched in a browser. Any help would be appreciated.
This is the async task

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",userid));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pswd",pswd));

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com/work/examplefolder/");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

this is my php code

```
$host='127.0.0.1';
$uname='root';
$pwd='';
$db="example";

$con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

//$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
//$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$pswd=$_REQUEST['pswd'];
$flag['code']=0;

if($r=mysql_query("insert into user(username,password) values('$id','$pswd')",$con))
{
    $flag['code']=1;

}

print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: why are you using httpclient ,it has been deprecated.

Comment: Why are you using PHP *mysql_* functions, they have been deprecated as well. Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Yes, I understand it's deprecated. Even though it should work right? Other than httpclient what should I use then?